# how to make a div left position according to another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div called `first` which width can be dynamic and horizontally centered according margin left right to auto

```
.first
{
    width:70%;
    background-color:#5b9a68;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Another div `second` with position `fixed`

```
.second
{
    position:fixed;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    left:input;
}
```

Html

```
<div class="first">content</div>
<div class="second">Left Value</div>
```

i want this `second` div to position according to `first` div.The Problem here is `second` div position is `fixed` so it is positioning according to screen width so i tried this script to position it according to `first` div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var input=0;

    var first_width = $(".first").width() / $('.first').parent().width() * 100;  
    var pos = (100-first_width)/2;//getting the empty part
    var ex_pos=pos+input;

    $('.second').css("left",ex_pos+"%");

});
```

Here when the input is zero it should start at the start of `first` div this is fine but when we changed the input value am not getting accurate percentage positioning according to `first` div.

Let say for example if i give 50 as input then i'll place it on 65 but this way am not perfectly positioning in 50 of `first` div.Also if i give 100% as input this will go outside.

How to do this if input is 100 then the `second` div should be at the end of `first` div.
if the input is 50 it should be at middle of `first` like that.

[Output With 0% left position](http://i42.tinypic.com/30tky8z.jpg)

[Output With 50% left position](http://i42.tinypic.com/ou12y9.jpg)

[Output With 100% left position](http://i44.tinypic.com/2vuwwn4.jpg)

**NOTE**-I don't want to change or edit the css. i would like to do it in script alone.
**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3NZbn/)**

Comment: you should use `position:absolute` instead of `position:fixed` and then place the second div inside the first div or why not just float the divs if you are wanting them side by side

Comment: You should add floats: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: Sorry,no css change should be there @Pete

Comment: w3schools is not a good source after all ..

Comment: What if you do this :  `if(input===100){
        ex_pos = ex_pos - 43;
    }`

See Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3NZbn/1/

Comment: Thank.Consider other percentages also @The Dark Knight

Comment: @sun Look at my answer below, which takes care of the 50% and 100% scenarios explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var input = 0,
        firstWidth = $('.first').width(),                    // width of first div
        secondWidth = $('.second').width(),                  // width of second div
        offset = (input * (firstWidth - secondWidth)) / 100, // % to shift
        leftPos = $('.first').offset().left;                 // left position of first div

    $('.second').css("left", leftPos + offset);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UpWjd/2/)

*From jQuery API Documentation : [Link](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)*

> The .offset() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element ***relative to the document***.
>   It returns an object containing the properties top and left.

So :

```
leftPos = $('.first').offset().left;
```

This gives us the left co-ordinates for the `.first` `div` i.e the point where it starts.

Comment: perfect. What i did on myfiddle line 4,5 is you did in one line itself as on line 6.i don't know this offset, could you help me to understand this offset in jquery. Thanks for the solution +1 @Nikhil Patel

Comment: Added some explanation. Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are looking for scenarios for 50% and 100% .

This should do it :

**JS :**

```
if(input===100){
    ex_pos = ex_pos - 43;
}else if(input===50){
    ex_pos = ex_pos - 13;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3NZbn/2/)

Comment: Am looking for all continuous percentage from 1% to 100%

Comment: i'll wait @The Dark Knight